# Substring-indexing in Oracle

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, indexing

I just found that our current database design is a little inefficient according to the `SELECT` queries we perform the most. IBANs are positional coordinates, according to nation-specific formats.

Since we mostly perform `JOIN`s and `WHERE`s on a precise substring of IBAN columns in some tables, my question is about assigning an index to the substring(s) of a column

Are we forced to add redundant and indexed columns to the table? Ie. add columns `NATION_CODE`, `IBAN_CIN`, `IT_CIN`, `IT_ABI`, `IT_CAB`, `IT_ACCOUNT` (where the IT_ fields are considered only for accounts starting in ITXX) each one with appropriate secondary indexing **or** is there any special kind of secondary index that can be applied only on a substring of a column?

The first solution could make the DB more complex since IBAN accounts are used all along the DBMS (and, obviously, I have no full control over design).

Thank you

[Edit] Typical query

```
SELECT * FROM DELEGATIONS WHERE SUBSTR(IBAN, 6, 5) IN (SELECT ABI FROM BANKS WHERE ANY_CONDITION)
```

Extracts all payment delegations where the target account belongs to any of the banks that match CONDITION. Should be changed to

```
SELECT * FROM DELEGATIONS WHERE SUBSTR(IBAN, 1, 2) = 'IT' AND SUBSTR(IBAN, 6, 5) IN (SELECT ABI FROM BANKS WHERE ANY_CONDITION)
```

to make sure that BBAN really holds the bank code in digits [6-11]

Comment: In the second example, the substr(IBAN, 1, 2) could be better written as IBAN like 'IT%'. That would use any existing index on the IBAN col as you are substr'ing from the start of the string. For the substr(IBAN, 6, 5), use a function based index as suggested below. Note that for the second example, Oracle will generally only use 1 index to answer the query, so whether it picks the index on IBAN or the function index is down to the statistics and the data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for a [function based index](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_indexes.htm#ADFNS258):

```
create index ix_substring on TABLE (substr(COLUMN, 4, 9))
```

Comment: The OP writes that the substring are DIFFERENT (positions that is) depending on how the string starts... which would mean you need to add some conditions like DECODE ot CASE WHEN into the index... from what I understand that won't work the way needed...

Comment: @Yahia, as far as I can see from the OP's question, there are only fixed substrings (although, of course for NATION_CODE, IBAN_CIN and so forth, which entails creating mutliple fb-indexes). I am ready to stand corrected, if I am wrong on this. If the OP posted a typical query (that needs a bit of performance boost) that could help.

Comment: Actually, I care more about the fact that such kind of indexing is feasible, rather than your (rightful) observation about CASEs. I'm going to post an example query. The truth behind everything is that our designer (maybe someone whose rules were posted on TDWTF.com) doesn't care about foreign IBANs, so we extract the bank/branch information from every IBAN in the DB, not only from those that start with IT

Comment: Even if the substrings are in different positions given various prefixes or something, this could easily be handled by a function-based index on a user-defined function. I think the only requirement for a user-defined function is that it must be defined as `DETERMINISTIC`.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Oracle 11g, you could look at using [virtual columns](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_7002.htm#BABIJABG) and then indexing those. This is pretty much equivalent to René's answer but might provide a bit more formality around the use of the data so that only the correct characters are used.

Virtual columns won't take up any additional space in the database, although any index you create on that virtual column will.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but unfortunately this is not 11g. When I wrote the question I really hoped a mechanism like virtual columns existed :)