# Improve performance in JDBC query - ArrayList comparison

Tags: java, sql, performance, jdbc

I've been trying to get the most efficient way to get a set of values from a DB and comparing them with their respective sub-string to save specific values... Here is an example: 
I have this table which contains a PRODUCT(ID), from the ones in LVL - 7  I have to substring the values until I get to LVL1

```
LVL     PRODUCT          DESCRIPTION
5       01AR2TGELL       DESLVL5
6       01AR2TGELLGS     DESLVL6
7       01AR2TGELLGSQKA  DESLVL7
6       01AR2TGELLDE     DESLVL6
7       01AR2TGELLDEUDP  DESLVL7
7       01AR2TGELLDEUZN  DESLVL7
```

So I can get something like this:

```
LVL   PRODUCT          DESCRIPTION  | LVL   PRODUCT        DESCRIPTION  | LVL  PRODUCT     DESCRIPTION
7     01AR2TGELLGSQKA  DESLVL7      | 6     01AR2TGELLGS   DESLVL6      | 5    01AR2TGELL  DESLVL5
7     01AR2TGELLDEUDP  DESLVL7      | 6     01AR2TGELLDE   DESLVL6      | 5    01AR2TGELL  DESLVL5
7     01AR2TGELLDEUZN  DESLVL7      | 6     01AR2TGELLDE   DESLVL6      | 5    01AR2TGELL  DESLVL5
```

I'm working with Java (Requirement) and also I'm using JDBC to connect to the Oracle DB. What I did is to get all the values from LVL7 with a query and save all those values in an ArrayList then, with a LVL and a Value of the PRODUCT Substring I compare the values, like this:

```
"select * from PRODHIERARCHY where LVL=7"
"select * from PRODHIERARCHY WHERE LVL= 6 AND PRODUCT_HIERARCHY="+"'"+descLv7.get(j).substring(0, descLv7.get(j).length() - 4)+"'"
```

My problem is, there is approx. 35 thousand LVL7 values, and in total around 65 thousand so this is very inefficient. (To get the 35 thousand LVL7 values takes around 3 minutes since the DB is processing everything, when it gets to the comparison with the ArrayList it takes around 30 minutes per LVL).

Can anyone please recommend me a way to modify either the query or my comparison process  so it takes about the same time as the first query? Thanks!

Comment: Just to add, I have two other approaches: one gets the comparison with the last value but needs to make a new connection every comparison of every LVL a lot more that my main solution. And the other one doesn't need to make a new connection, butI keep getting a java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset

Comment: Hola! I don't quite get the DB structure so I could advice better. But what I could recommend is 1) index the columns you need to search upon. You could use function based index [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487520/substring-indexing-in-oracle) 2) Or you could put some [virtual columns](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_7002.htm#BABIJABG) and index those so you could build a recursive view and make the selection through the view leaving the heavy stuff to the database. Hope this ideas help!

Comment: And like Hazel would say: elaborate. A little more info on data structure or DB table design could help us understand more and give you more insight.

Comment: This is definitely something you need to try to solve on the DB side before trying to solve it on the application side. Get the best Oracle guy you have to craft indexes and a good query for it, or ask on dba.SE.

Comment: Thank you both
@lazha The first table is pretty much the DB. It has LVL7, 6,5,4,3,2,1. Every LVL7 is an unique ID, which are branches of a LVL6-PRODUCT, which are branches of a LVL5-PRODUCT and so on. I need to get the description of all the levels depending on the substring, as I tried to represent on the second table.
Thanks for the comments, I'll check both links!
Kayaman I posted this on friday but  I think I didn't explain myself haha
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59506632/how-can-i-create-a-sub-query-from-the-same-table-sql-developer?

Comment: Nope you did not explained quite well LOL!!! It took me a while to figure it out what you needed. Hope the answer helps just an Idea to solve your predicament.

Comment: Are you key with **fixed length** per level, i.e. for LVL6 always of length 12 etc? This is crutial for the performance of the query...

Comment: @MarmiteBomber For what I've been told, The LVL7 PRODUCT is variable, for LVL6 i need to remove the last 4 characters, LVL5 is the subtring of the first 11 characters of LVL7, LVL4 the same as LVL5 but 8 characters, LVL3 6 character, LVL2 4 characters, and LVL1 2 characters. I'm pretty sure the length of LVL7 is always 18 charcaters, and LVL6 14 characters. I haven't compared every single value yet. And no, I don't htink I have a key on fixed length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** I don't have Oracle, so I made it with MSSQL, just use **substr** instead of **left** for the artificial keys.

Here's an static idea. Lets see, first let us create a view with some computed columns (artificial keys)
*(or you could add them to your product table and index them)*

```
create view vw_product_computed as
select
    a.lvl,
    a.Product,
    left(a.product, 12) as a12, -- your first lelvel down (artificial key) 
    left(a.product, 10) as a10  -- your seccond level down (artificial key) 
from
    products a;
```

Then is just a matter of joining your product table with your view using your artificial keys:

```
select
    *
from
    desarrollo.vw_product_computed a
join dbo.products b on b.product = a.a12
join dbo.products c on c.product = a.a10
where
    a.lvl = 7;
```

And off you go, you have your result set as you need it:
[image: Join Result]

If you would like to make it a dynamic thing I guess a pivot table may come in handy.

Hope this helps mate.

Comment: Sorry for inactivity...
Oh, I see. Thank you so much, I'll check and soon post an update if it worked!

Comment: Acabo de ver que eres de México también, soy nuevo usuario en la plataforma también jaja
Te agradezco de nuevo! y feliz año :)

Comment: Ok, I finally implemented it and works just as I wanted. Muchas gracias!
Now I hope this is the best solution.